# Iterating HashMap that has a non-string key-pair and ArrayList as a value

Tags: arraylist, hashmap, iterator, iteration, freemarker

I am passing the following via Controller:

```
HashMap<SomeClassA, ArrayList<SomeClassB>>
```

SomeClassA and SomeClassB are not primitives, and are coded by me. Their getters are either Strings or Longs. Lets call the HashMap variable a `map123`.

What I am trying to do is have something like this code:

```
<#list map123?keys as key> 
    ${key} = ${map123[key]} 
</#list>
```

However, what I get is that map123[key] is a NULL !
This means that I cannot iterate the ArrayList.

What did I do wrong (or what am I supposed to do at all) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily the most problematic legacy in FreeMarker 2, but it has workarounds. The `[]` operator doesn't support non-string keys. It would be an error, but due the unlucky cooperation with yet another legacy, usually what happens is that the lookup is silently done with the `toString()` of the object, and so you simply don't find the item.

Workaround: If you just need to iterate, just use at least version `2.3.25-incubating` (that's a stable final release) and write:

```
<#list map123 as key, value> 
    ${key} = ${value} 
</#list>
```

If you have to get values by key otherwise, then you can fall back to the Java API of `Map`: `map123?api.get(key)`. (Note that `?api` has to be explicitly enabled in the FreeMarker configuration, but the error message will tell that.)

Comment: The FreeMarker version I am using is integrated in a FrameWork, so unless the framework updates, I can't change the versions. So, the workaround I have to use is to improvise by joining only the values I need from the SomeClassA and SomeClassB into a single SomeClassC and pass it as a List.

Comment: If you can't override that version with a higher one (because the framework isn't just a Maven dependency) then perhaps the cleanest solution is to expose (or pull in via `?new`) some utility `TemplateMethodModelEx` implementation that gets the Java `Map` out of its argument via `WrapperTemplateModel.getWrappedObject()`, then constructs the desired result list. So then you can use something like `<#list mapEntries(map123) as kvp>${kvp.key} = ${kvp.value}`.

Comment: Also note that `?api` was introduced in FreeMarker 2.3.22, which isn't exactly new. If you have `?api` at least, then you can do `<#list map123?api.entrySet() as kvp>${kvp.key} = ${kvp.value}`.

Comment: Thanks, I think it was just "the end of a day" yesterday and that I was lazy to try it. It is more complicated than a Maven dependency, but I think I got the version high enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use key-value pairs (since 2.3.25)

```
<#list map123 as key, value> 
    ${key} = ${value} 
</#list>
```

you can try

```
<#list map123.entrySet() as entry >
    ${entry.key} = ${entry.value}
</#list>
```

you can easily check `null` values with `?exists` directive or just `${entry.value!"default"}`